# How can i know even and odd numbers from input by user in array? -c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on a program to count how many even numbers or odd numbers using Array, The User Input amount of array (if they input 4, there will be 4 looping of input numbers value) and i don't know how to count up even numbers or odd numbers from an Array..

```
#include<stdio.h> int main(){
int array[10];
int i,j,k;

printf("Amount of Array :");
scanf("%d", &j);

for(i=0;i<j;i++){
printf(" %d value : ",i+1);
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

printf("Amount of even numbers : %d", array[i]%2 );}
```

The finished program need to be like:

> Amount Of Array: 5 (*)
>
> 1st value : 6 (*)
>
> 2nd value : 7 (*)
>
> 3rd value : 2 (*)
>
> 4th value : 3 (*)
>
> 5th value : 6 (*)
>
> Amount of even numbers :3
>
> The Even numbers are: 6 , 2 ,6
>
> Amount of odd numbers :2
>
> The odd numbers are: 7 , 3

*User input

Something like that, don't mind the ordinal indicator (-st,-nd,-rd) it's not written in english in the real program, sorry if there's some mispelled..

Comment: Sum is done with *addition* (+). I don't see any in your code.

Comment: perform the sum in the loop: `if (array[i]%2) odds+= array[i] else evens += array[i]`

Comment: How do i write it with the array?

Comment: The word "Sum" should be "Amount" (given the example output). So, you need to count how many even/odd numbers there are, not sum them up.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what  i mean, corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int array[10];
  int i,j,k;

  int even_number_count;
  int odd_number_count;

  printf("Amount of Array :");
  scanf("%d", &j);

  for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf(" %d value : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }

  even_number_count=0;
  odd_number_count=0;

  printf("Even numbers are: ");
  for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
      printf("%d  ", array[i]);
      even_number_count++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("Odd numbers are: ");
  for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
      printf("%d  ", array[i]);
      odd_number_count++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("Amount of even numbers : %d\n", even_number_count );
  printf("Amount of odd numbers : %d\n", odd_number_count );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Man, that's solve it all, thank you David!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a few things:

1. A variable to count even numbers
2. A variable to count odd numbers
3. An array for the even numbers (since you have to present them at the end, you don't necessarily need this, but I think it's a good way to learn how to deal with arrays)
4. An array for the odd numbers (you don't necessarily need this one either, but again...)

Then, whenever you read a number from the user input, you should also check if that number is odd or even and do the proper calculations.

Comment: So i need to split one array into two? the one is even and the other is odd? then i can call them up and count how many elements in the even array and the odd array?

Comment: That would work, not the most optimized implementation but it would definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main() 
 {

  int array[10];
  int index,length,evencount;

  printf("Amount of Array :");
  scanf("%d", &length);

  for(index=0;index<length;index++){
     printf(" %d value : ",index+1);
     scanf("%d", &array[index]);
  }

  for(index=0;array[index]%2==0 && index<length ;index++)
     evencount++;

  printf("\n\nAmount of even numbers :%d\nThe Even numbers are:",evencount);
  for(index=0;index<length;index++)
      (array[index]%2==0)?printf("%d ",array[index]):printf(" ");

   printf("\n\nAmount of odd numbers :%d\nThe odd numbers are:",length-evencount);
  for(index=0;index<length;index++)
      (array[index]%2!=0)?printf("%d ",array[index]):printf(" ");

   return 0;
   }
```